# Gradle rootproject method call fails

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle and try to upgrade our build environment ant to gradle. i have a multiple project build configuration. What i want to do is read the .classpath file from eclipse and add to gradle dependency. Below code implements this and works fine in the gradle.build file under the project,

```
def add(String kind, String dependency) {  
          project.dependencies 
          {dep->
              if(kind.equals("lib"))
              {
                def jar = dependency.substring(dependency.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
                jar = jar.substring(0,jar.indexOf("."))
                dep.compile("jarlib:$jar:0")
              }
              else if(kind.equals("src"))
              {
                def project_name = dependency.substring(dependency.indexOf("/") + 1)                
                dep.compile(project(":$project_name"))              
              }                     
        } 
  }
```

But i do not want to copy this method to every subproject and move it to root project gradle file. After this i get an error at line `dep.compile(project(":$project_name"))` as

> > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated.compile()
> >     is applicable for argum ent types:
> >     (org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject_Decorated) values:
> >     [project ':MYPROJECT']

And this is the caller task

```
task loadClasspath {
    File classpathFile = new File(projectDir.getPath() + '/.classpath') 
    println "################ COMPILING PROJECT ################"
    println "################" + project.name +"################"
    println "###################################################"
    if(!classpathFile.exists())
        return

    def classpath = (new XmlParser()).parse(classpathFile)
        classpath.classpathentry.each{ module ->
              println "Kind : " +  module.@kind + ", path : " + module.@path
              add(module.@kind,module.@path)
        }           
        project.configurations.compileClasspath.each { file -> println file }
    }
```

Anyone can help ?

Comment: What if you add the function definition to the `subProjects` section of root build.gradle?

Comment: adding method in subProjects section causes compile error. gradle does not allow as i see